# Why do I always get a message that there are insufficient money, even though the amount I'm withdrawing is less than my balance?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I intended to show the user the message "insufficient balance" when the amount he wants to withdraw is larger than the available balance, but the message appears even when the amount he wants to withdraw is less. What's the problem here, exactly?

**Views**

```
def create_withdrawal_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        withdraw_form = WithdrawalForm(request.POST)
        if withdraw_form.is_valid():
            investment = withdraw_form.save(commit=False)
            if investment.balance < investment.amount:
                messages.success(request, 'insufficient funds')
            else:
                investment.balance -= investment.withdraw_amount
                investment.save()
                messages.success(request, 'investment successful')
    else:

        withdraw_form = WithdrawalForm()
    context = {'withdraw_form': withdraw_form}
    return render(request, 'create-withdrawal.html', context)
```

**My Model**

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    PLAN_CHOICES = (
        ("Basic - Daily 2% for 180 Days", "Basic - Daily 2% for 180 Days"),
        ("Premium - Daily 4% for 360 Days", "Premium - Daily 4% for 360 Days"),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PLAN_CHOICES, null=True)
    deposit_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    basic_interest = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    premium_interest = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    investment_return = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    withdraw_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    locked_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    investment_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

**My Model Forms**

```
class InvestmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ['deposit_amount', 'plan']


class WithdrawalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ['withdraw_amount']
```

My **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.list_investments, name='list-investments'),
    path('create/', views.create_investment_view, name='create-investment'),
    path('withdraw/', views.create_withdrawal_view, name='withdraw'),
]
```

Comment: Provide your `InvestmentForm` class please.

Comment: Your InvestmentForm doesn't have some fields that you mentioned in your view function.

Comment: @enesislam I have updated my question with the class model. Note, I declared the same model class in the two model forms.

Comment: @allexiusw I have updated my questions with more information

Comment: From what I can see, Your variable investment is coming from the form.  It doesn't appear that it would have the current users balance information, so in your views you would want to grab the user with something like:     Investment_user = investments. objects.get(user=request.user).      Then you could compare investment_user.balance to investment.withdraw

Comment: Provide `urls.py` file...

Comment: @allexiusw I updated the question. You can find the urs.py included.

Answer (score 1):

Believe you are using the wrong data here:

```
def create_withdrawal_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        withdraw_form = WithdrawalForm(request.POST)
        if withdraw_form.is_valid():
            investment = withdraw_form.save(commit=False)
            if investment.balance < withdraw_form.withdraw_amount:
                messages.success(request, 'insufficient funds')
            else:
                investment.balance -= withdraw_amount.withdraw_amount
                investment.save()
                messages.success(request, 'investment successful')
    else:
        withdraw_form = WithdrawalForm()
    context = {'withdraw_form': withdraw_form}
    return render(request, 'create-withdrawal.html', context)
```

You have to validate the data of your form `withdraw_form.withdraw_amount`. not `instance.amount`.

But also you have in some way to get the investment from where you need to withdraw I believe you need to get the `pk` and do something like this:

```
investment = Investment.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Comment: It's a model form with all form fields validated and an investment object that interacts with all of them. Am I correct?